# Is sterescope still used to do cartography with orthophotography?

Tags: geology, geomorphology, instrumentation, cartography

I used this tool at my degree a couple of lusters ago to do cartography with aerial [orthophotos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthophoto). We used it on cartography and geomorphology subjets.

> [image: stereoscope]
>
> Source: [gumtree.com](https://www.gumtree.com.au/s-ad/somerset/collectables/vintage-waterworth-hobart-cartographers-stereoscope/1200938399)

The method consists on using two consecutive but overlaped orthophotos (on east-west direction) taken from a plane, so an optical effect allows you to see the relief. Then you can delimite units with a marcker pen on a transparent film. We after transpose the cartography to a topographic map.

**My question is if this tool is still used at university and among working geologists.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working in an academic environment and I know these tools are still shown to undergrads along other modern photo-interpretation techniques.

Often, modern techniques are more straightforward and convenient. There is a wide coverage of decent, recent and cheap satellite images available, providing a lot to work with in a short amount of time, easily compared to the interpretation of orthophotos. Elevation models, multi-bands and high resolution are big plus for modern techniques in a GIS for instance. Not counting just bringing a drone and ortho-photograph everything.

Where available stereo-pairs are somewhat older (50's to 80's) and of a limited/specific coverage depending on the region of interest - so this need to be considered.

But I also use stereo-pairs when I go in a tent at the tip of the globe where technology break, battery drains and internet lack. Portable stereoscope work well in the field.